# Docker Machine to a remote server

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I understaand that when I create a VM with Docker Machine using the *Virtualbox driver*, it creates a local VM running the boot2docker distribution. I can then create my containers on it using for instance Docker Compose.

**But what exactly happens when you use Docker Machine onto a remote server?** Does it create a VM on that remote server?

Does it differ if you use a known provider (using say the *AWS driver*) or an unknown provider (using the *generic driver*)?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Digital Ocean, AWS etc, you give Docker machine an API key, which it will use to create a VM. It will then install the Docker daemon and any dependencies and configure remote access. So you don't give it a remote server - it creates one.

If you use the generic driver, you give Docker machine SSH access to an IP, where I presume it again installs Docker and configures remote access (so it effectively skips the creation step).